# ICS calendar not rendered in Gmail where ORGANIZER is the same as the To

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api

I have a service where people can create an restaurant appointment for themselves. They use their own email address to create the appointment.

After they created the appointment I would like to send them an email with the event attached so they can add the event to their calendar.

So the From in the email is the restaurant email and the To i the email of the person that created the appointment

The interesting part of the ICS attached looks like this:

ORGANIZER;CN=Henrik Gemal;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=CHAIR:mailto:my@own_email.address
ATTENDEE;ROLE=CHAIR;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:mailto:my@own_email.address

The problem is that Gmail does not render the ICS file. It just shows it as an attachment.

I think this is because the ORGANIZER is the same as the creator

So if "my@own_email.address" is a Gmail address then the calendar is not rendered.

Isn't it possible to send a calendar to Gmail where the ORGANIZER is the same as the To field?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is too late to give you an answer. But I'm in the same situation, and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084236/icalendar-does-not-create-an-event-for-organizer/17669437#17669437) that helped me to understand that the problem is with the RFC2445 iCalendar specification. So .. to respond your question... No, you can't send a calendar reminder to the organizer is the same as the attendee.

Look at the link I give, there is a better explanation, and possible solution for you (and either for me)