# Outlook deletes my programmatically-created meeting

Tags: asp.net, email, calendar, outlook, exchange-server

I'm sending some programmatically-created meetings to Exchange 2010 accounts through an ASP.NET application. Everyone receives without any problem the invitation email except the organizer, whose Outlook 2013 sends it to the Deleted Items folder directly. "Meeting cannot be found in the Calendar", it says.

I imagine it's happening because indeed the organizer does not have that meeting in his calendar and Outlook fails trying to set everything for him.

Here's the body:

```
string strBodyCalendar = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nMETHOD:REQUEST\r\nPRODID:Microsoft CDO for Microsoft Exchange\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nBEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\nTZID:(GMT-06.00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-TZID:11\r\nBEGIN:STANDARD\r\nDTSTART:16010101T020000\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:-0500\r\nTZOFFSETTO:-0600\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU\r\nEND:STANDARD\r\nBEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\nDTSTART:16010101T020000\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:-0600\r\nTZOFFSETTO:-0500\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU\r\nEND:DAYLIGHT\r\nEND:VTIMEZONE\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTAMP:{8}\r\nDTSTART:{0}\r\nSUMMARY:{7}\r\nUID:{5}\r\nATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=\"{9}\":MAILTO:{9}\r\nACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=\"{4}\":MAILTO:{4}\r\nORGANIZER;CN=\"{3}\":mailto:{4}\r\nLOCATION:{2}\r\nDTEND:{1}\r\nDESCRIPTION:{7}\\N\r\nSEQUENCE:1\r\nPRIORITY:5\r\nCLASS:\r\nCREATED:{8}\r\nLAST-MODIFIED:{8}\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-1\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-ATTENDEE-CRITICAL-CHANGE:{8}\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNER-CRITICAL-CHANGE:{8}\r\nBEGIN:VALARM\r\nACTION:DISPLAY\r\nDESCRIPTION:REMINDER\r\nTRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT00H15M00S\r\nEND:VALARM\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR\r\n";
strBodyCalendar = string.Format(strBodyCalendar, dtStart.ToUniversalTime().ToString(strCalDateFormat), dtEnd.ToUniversalTime().ToString(strCalDateFormat),
        strLocation, strOrganizerName, strOrganizerEmail, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"), strSummary, strSubject,
        DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(strCalDateFormat), macAttendeeList.ToString());
```

I'm not sure how to format the body to show that user as the sender (and organizer?) without making Outlook going crazy trying to find something that does not exist.

Through the website I don't have permissions to access the organizer's calendar and create the meeting before sending anything.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer also in Stack Overflow. Silly me.

[iCalendar does not create an event for organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084236/icalendar-does-not-create-an-event-for-organizer#17669437)

Anyway, it cannot be done by sending an email as the organizer, what I want and need; but you can use EWS for sending appointments as a specific account to which you have access. Bummer.