# Organizer mentioned in the Icalendar in not showing the meeting invite calender in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, icalendar, organizer

I am using icalendar gem in rails to render calendar in meeting invite when sending mail through rails application.

Here is my code to do that:

```
      mails = mail(:from => "organizer@email.com",:to => "organizer@email.com,recipient@email.com",:subject => "subject") do |format|
    format.html { render "my_content_partial" }
      format.ics {
           ical = Icalendar::Calendar.new
           ical.custom_property("X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN", "TRUE")
           e = Icalendar::Event.new
           e.start = DateTime.parse(start_time)
           e.start.icalendar_tzid="UTC" 
           e.end =  DateTime.parse(end_time)
           e.end.icalendar_tzid="UTC"
           e.klass "PRIVATE"
           e.organizer "organizer@email.com"
           e.attendees ["mailto: my@email.com"]
           e.summary "#{subject}"  #builds the title of the meeting in calendar
           e.custom_property("LOCATION", "my location")

           ical.add_event(e)
           ical.custom_property("METHOD", "REQUEST")
           render :text => ical.to_ical
      }
     mails.deliver
```

The issue I am facing is that the email sent to the recipient@email.com contains calender in   it but not showing in the organizer@email.com's email.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: should organizer also use "mailto:"?  I've familiarized myself with icalendar in the past, but never used that gem, so I can't say for sure what the syntax here should be, but looking at my own code I have... "ORGANIZER:mailto:" + recipient

Comment: Yes have tried this but still same problem :(

Comment: I would recommend making a very similar invitation using the calendar program (probably outlook for you?) and opening the actual icalendar files for comparison...

Comment: My requirement is to show calender in the email itself. The actual files are same.

Comment: what do you mean by "in the email itself"?

Comment: Try to use `METHOD:PUBLISH` as mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21418513/1685980

Comment: @user3334690 I mean it should not be an attachment, calender should be rendered as it.